# Add 'page-attributes' to woocommerce supports

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

By default in the woocommerce plugin, it supports only

```
 $supports = array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'thumbnail', 'custom-fields',
 'publicize', 'wpcom-markdown' );
```

in class-wc-post-types.php. I want to utilize the default `page-attributes` into the supports for the Woocommerce CPT. Is there a function/filter available to tap into that class?

Comment: You can modify what already existing post types support via https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support

Comment: Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to utilize the default page-attributes into the supports for the Woocommerce CPT. Is there a function/filter available to tap into that class?

From looking at the source code of that class, it doesn’t look like it.

But you can modify what already existing post types support via [`add_post_type_support`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_post_type_support).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @cBroe. This works for that post type. I just added a conditional to work if woocommerce is active.

```
if ( in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) {

    function wpcodex_add_excerpt_support_for_pages() {
        add_post_type_support( 'product', 'page-attributes' );
    }

    add_action( 'init', 'wpcodex_add_excerpt_support_for_pages' );

}
```